# MFC transfer CEdit control text to a CString

Tags: c++, mfc

So, i've got a CString and an CEdit control declared in the header of my CDialog class.

```
CString m_strRem;
CEdit m_editRem;
```

Ok, when i try to get the text from edit control, i use

```
m_editRem.GetWindowText(m_strRem);
```

but `m_strRem` is shown as a `<Bad Ptr>` after the operation.

If i declare another `CString` and use the same method, the text is passed to the new `CString`

```
CString strVal;
m_editRemorca.GetWindowText(strVal);
```

but again, if i want to pass `strVal` to `m_strRem`,  `m_strRem` is a `<Bad Ptr>`.

And i can't get to the bottom of this.

Comment: How is m_editRem initialized ? In which methods is the code you mention ? Show some more code please.

Comment: Agreed. More code please, there's stuff we can't see.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but the mistake was all mine. I was in Release mode and i guess that variables declared in header files are not always shown with their values when peeked at. The code works fine afterall.